# 'to_a' is not a method in 'Range', yet, it works on 'Range'?

Tags: ruby

The following code is valid:

```
(1..5).to_a
```

`(1..5)` is a `Range`. The method `to_a` appears to convert a range to an array.

However, the documentation for [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Range.html) does not document. Since this documentation is presumably auto-generated from the source with Yard, I doubt it could not be in the list of methods. Is there auto conversion going on?

How is the above legal Ruby?

Comment: `(1..3).method(:to_a).owner #=> Enumerable`, so see [Enumerable#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a). Recall `Range.ancestors #=> [Range, Enumerable, Object,...]`.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry, like I said, I'm a newbie.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: `(1..3)` is a `Range` instance so `m = (1..3).method(:to_a) #=> #<Method: Range(Enumerable)#to_a>` returns the method object associated with the symbol `:to_a` when defined on a `Range` instance. `m.owner #=> Enumerable` tells you where the method is defined. (Look carefully at the return value from  `(1..3).method(:to_a)` to see we really didn't need `owner`.) See [Object#method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-method) and [Method#owner](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Method.html#method-i-owner). Lastly, note one could write `Range.instance_method(:to_a).owner` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following code is valid ruby:
>
> ```
> b = (1..5).to_a
> ```
>
> `(1..5)` is a `Range` object, and `b` is an `Array` object.  The official(?) documentation for the Class [Range](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Range.html) does not document the method `to_a`, which appears to convert a range to an array.
>
> So, how is the above legal Ruby?

Ruby has something called "inheritance". Inheritance is a method for differential code-reuse that actually does not only exist in Ruby, but is in fact quite popular in many languages such as Java, C♯, C++, Python, PHP, Scala, Kotlin, Ceylon, and so on and so forth.

Inheritance allows you to define methods in one place, and then *inherit* them in another place, overriding and defining *only* the methods whose behavior *differs*. Hence, "differential code re-use".

In this particular case, the method you are looking at is [`Enumerable#to_a`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a).

Note: Ruby actually has two forms of inheritance, *mixin inheritance* and *class inheritance*. Mixin inheritance is like class inheritance where the mixin doesn't know its superclass. (The definitive resource about mixin inheritance is [Gilad Bracha](http://bracha.org/)'s PhD Thesis [*The Programming Language Jigsaw – Mixins, Modularity, and Multiple Inheritance*](http://bracha.org/jigsaw.ps).)

> The official(?) documentation

Actually, ruby-doc is a third-party site. There is no official documentation site. (However, the documentation on ruby-doc is generated from documentation comments in YARV, one of the major Ruby implementations, and one that Yukihiro Matsumoto actively contributes to.)

> Since this documentation is presumably autogenerated from the source with Yard,

It is actually autogenerated from the YARV source with RDoc, not YARD.

> I'm confused how it could not be in the list of methods,

Note that the explanation I gave is the correct one, but there could be many other explanations. The most simple one: the reason why the method is not in the documentation is that it is not documented. Another reason could be a bug in the documentation generator that prevents the documentation for that method being displayed, a typo in the source code that prevents the documentation generator from recognizing the documentation, and many, many others.

> so is there auto conversion going on?

No. Ruby does not have automatic conversions in the language. There are *some* methods which for reasons of efficiency are implemented in a non-object-oriented manner, and require an object to be an instance of a *specific* class (as opposed to the object-oriented manner, which would only require the object to conform to a specific protocol). Because it is a severe restriction to require an object to be an instance of a specific class, those methods will usually offer an "escape hatch" to the programmer, by sending a specific message and allowing the object to respond with an object of the required class.

For example, all methods printing something to the console, require an instance of `String`, but they will try sending `to_s` first, before rejecting the argument.

These are *sometimes* called "implicit conversions", but they have nothing to do with implicit conversions as in Scala or implicit casts as in C♯. They are in fact not even part of the language, they are just a convention for library writers.